# Counting number of graphs containing only paths from the origin back to itself

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

This is a combinatorics problem that came up for me.
Suppose you have n vertices, one of which is the "origin".  Count the number of directed graphs on this set of vertices such that

1. If you start at the origin and follow any path, you can always get back to the origin
2. Every edge is reachable from the origin

I guess put another way, I want to count "multi-paths" from the origin back to itself.

I would love a recursive formula in n (or double recursive in n and something else, not sure what), or ideas for an algorithm to compute it, or "I think this is somehow very hard".

Combinatorics is not my strong suite.  I have no ideas if this problem is impossibly hard or trivial.  Any tips appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My standard thought with these types of problems is to count manually for small values and then use induction